# Overloading += operator in C++ - How do you pass the left operand?

Tags: c++, parameters, operator-overloading, operands

I need to create an operator that accepts a double 'parameter'.

```
myClass myobject();

double mydouble = 10000;

mydouble += myobject;
```

My operator:

```
double operator+=(double value, const myclass& object)
{
    value += object.value;           
    return  value;
}
```

The parameter value is being passed to the operator += as zero, even though mydouble is initialized to 10000.

How do you create an operator that can accept the left operand as a parameter?

Comment: Do you mean that `value` doesn't change because you forgot to pass `value` by reference?

Comment: Also `myClass myobject();` is a function called `myobject` taking no parameters and returning a `myClass`. See most vexing parse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct prototype is the following:

```
double& operator+=(double& value, const myClass& obj)
```

Comment: See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment) for a complete list of inside and outside class overloading of assignment operators.

Comment: @crayzeewulf my answer is compliant with your suggested link.

Comment: Yes, your answer is totally correct and compliant with that link. Sorry for any confusion; I did not mean my comment to be a correction to your answer but rather an addendum for the sake of the OP. And partly also a note for future myself (or others) to look up a complete list if I (they) come across this question again. :D