# Why is my overloading operator returning zero?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, return-value

For whatever reason when I try to return a value from my overloaded function it is returning zero. I just started using overloading the other day so I am quite new to it, so if it is a simple mistake I am sorry about that.

It is quite strange because when I `cout` the values in the function, it shows exactly what I want to see, however when I return it, it still returns a empty value, which is zero.

The function is this:

```
double operator+=(double ls, Account& rs){
    //cout << ls << endl;
    //cout << rs._balance+ ls << endl;
    return ls+=rs._balance;



    //return rs._balance+=ls;
}
```

Here is the full .cpp file including the function:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Account.h"
using namespace std;
namespace sict{
    Account::Account(){
        _name[0] = 0;
        _balance = 0;
    }

    Account::Account(double balance){
        _name[0] = 0;
        _balance = balance;
    }

    Account::Account(const char name[], double balance){
        strncpy(_name, name, 40);
        _name[40] = 0;
        _balance = balance;
    }

    void Account::display()const{

        for(int x = 0; x < 40; x++){
            if(_name[x] == '\0')
                x = 40;
            else
                cout << _name[x];
        }

    cout << ": $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << _balance;

    }

    Account Account::operator+(Account ls) {

        return ls._balance + _balance;
    }

    double operator+=(double ls, Account& rs){
        //cout << ls << endl;
        //cout << rs._balance+ ls << endl;
        return ls+=rs._balance;



        //return rs._balance+=ls;
    }

    Account Account::operator+=(Account& ls){

        return  _balance+=ls._balance;

    }

    Account::Account(const char name[]){
        strncpy(_name, name, 40);
    }

    char* Account::getName(){

        return _name;
    }

    double Account::getBal(){

        return _balance;
    }

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ls, Account& rs){
        rs.display();
        return ls;
    }

    Account& Account::operator=(Account& ls){
        if( !strcmp(ls._name,"") &&ls._balance > 0)
        {
            strcpy(_name, "Saving");
        }

        _balance = ls._balance;
        //strcpy(_name, ls._name);

        return *this;

    }

    char* Account::operator=(char* ls){

        strcpy(_name, ls);

        return _name;

    }


}
```

Here is the header file:

```
#ifndef SICT_ACCOUNT_H__
#define SICT_ACCOUNT_H__
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
namespace sict{
    class Account{
        char _name[41];
        double _balance;
    public:
        Account();
        Account::Account(double balance);
        Account::Account(const char name[], double balance);
        Account::Account(const char name[]);
        Account& operator=(Account& ls);
        Account operator+=(Account& ls);
        char* operator=(char* ls);
        void display()const;
        double getBal();
        char* getName();

        friend double operator+=(double ls, Account& rs);
        Account operator+(Account ls);

    };

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ls, Account& rs);
};

#endif
```

And here is the main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Account.h"

using namespace sict;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Account A;
  Account B("Saving", 10000.99);
  Account C("Checking", 100.99);

  double value = 0;

  cout << A << endl << B << endl << C << endl << "--------" << endl;

  A = B + C;
  A = "Joint";

  cout << A << endl << B << endl << C << endl << "--------" << endl;

  A = B += C;

  cout << A << endl << B << endl << C << endl << "--------" << endl;

  value += A;
  value += B;
  value += C;

  cout << "Total balance: " << value << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33550749/overloading-operator-in-c-how-do-you-pass-the-left-operand/33550939#33550939

Comment: @A.S.H, I googled up how to do this, but didn't find an answer, didn't think it was a duplicate but okay...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For

```
value += A;
value += B;
value += C;
```

to work, you'll have to change the argument of the overloaded operator function to be a reference. Right now, it gets passed by value. The value gets modified in the function but that doesn't change the value in the calling function.

Instead of

```
double operator+=(double ls, Account& rs){
```

use

```
double operator+=(double& ls, Account& rs){
                     // ^^
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, can't believe that it was something so simple that I missed, much appreciated.

Comment: @AsadMahmood, don't feel bad. Most of us have gone through those kinds of mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

In order for this to work you need to capture the left hand argument by reference.

```
double operator+=(double ls, Account& rs)
```

Needs to be

```
double operator+=(double& ls, Account& rs)
```